How do we calculate the amount of NaOH to be added to make a solution of 0.8N to 1N?
As we know NaOH is secondary solution and we have to standardise it.
So i made 1N NaOH solution but after standardising with a standard acid, the normality of solution comes 0.82N.
So how do I calculate the amount needed to make 1N NaOH solution?
also vice versa suppose if i get the normality more than the desired one so how i calculate how much amount of distilled water to be added to make it 1N?

Suppose the volume of the $0.8$ N $\ce{NaOH}$ solution is exactly $1.00$ liter. As such, it contains $0.8$ mole $\ce{NaOH}$, or $32$ g NaOH. If  this solution is to be transformed into a $1$M $\ce{NaOH}$ solution, the difference in mass is $40 - 32 = 8$ g $\ce{NaOH}$. So, as the liquid volume change is negligible, $8.00$ g $\ce{NaOH}$ has to be added to $1.00$ liter of the original $0.8$ M solution, and stirred until complete dissolution. That's all.

and how much water should be added to make it 1N?

Don't add water to the $0.8$ M solution. Add some solid $\ce{NaOH}$ as explained in my answer, dissolve it, and this is all. The final solution is $1$ M, or $1$ N.
